# I have xcode 3.2.2, is that the latest? Is 4.0 out

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to get into iphone dev, I downloaded xcode a long time ago and my version on my mac is 3.2.2

I logged into the dev center, and I see "xcode and ios sdk 4.2"

The snowleapords download shows xcode 3.2.5 and ios sdk 4.2

Little confused, where is xcode 4.0 which I thought was released a while ago?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Xcode 4 has not been released yet. It's still in the developer preview stage (only available to members of the paid developer program). The current public stable version (as of this writing) is 3.2.5.

Comment: are people using it to release iphone apps or its too beta?

Comment: @Blankman: I don't know about others, but I'm not using it yet.

Comment: Apple explicitly tells developers to not use Xcode 4 yet for submitting apps. It is also still relatively buggy (you can be sure to have a crash each day).

Answer (score 1):

XCode 4 is still a beta. You must be a paid registered Mac developer or iOS developer to access the XCode 4 beta. It costs $100/year. The current release is 3.2.5, which includes the 4.2 SDK.

Comment: or a registered iOS developer.

Comment: Thanks, I just fixed it. I wasn't sure 'cause I'm a member of both.